# how can i make a link download when clicked

Tags: html, hyperlink, download

can i make an `<a> tag` download when clicked ? if not what should i do to download the content of it ? thank you  the href of the  contains the path and name of an image saved to the server

```
 echo('<tr>
         <td>&diams; <a href="'.$row['file_path'].$row['file_name'].'">'.$row['file_name'].'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
           <input type="submit" value="go to sign " name="submit" style="margin-left:165px" />
         </td>
       </tr>');
```

Comment: what has to be downloaded? i mean the file type to be downloaded.

Comment: also, which Server side language are you using? is it php or java or c# ?

Comment: simply, if you want to dounload a file, you should put it's link in the href property `<a href="text1.txt">download</a>`

Comment: i am using php and the file is an image png extension

Comment: Try `echo('<tr>
         <td>&diams; <a href="'.$row['file_path'].$row['file_name'].'" download>'.$row['file_name'].'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
           <input type="submit" value="go to sign " name="submit" style="margin-left:165px" />
         </td>
       </tr>');`

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`download`** attribute of HTML5

According to the docs

> The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded
>   when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/k4u7wyzx/)

HTML code

```
<a href="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" download>Download
</a>
```

So, change your code as follows

```
echo('<tr> <td>&diams; <a href="'.$row['file_path'].$row['file_name'].'" download>'.$row['file_name'].'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="go to sign " name="submit" style="margin-left:165px" /> </td> </tr>');
```

add a download attribute to `<a>`.